# How can add separate default routes for GET and POST requests in ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Currently I have the following in my Startup.cs class:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action=Get}");
    });
```

All my MVC controllers have a method Get on them, and a number of them have a Post as well. Something like this:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public MyType Get()
    {
        return GetMyTypeFromSomewhere();
    }

    [HttpPost("api/[controller]")]
    public void Post([FromBody]MyType updated)
    {
        //do some stuff with the new instance
    }
}
```

Currently I need to have `("api/[controller]")` on the Post method so that post requests will reach it.

I wish to be able to remove this and redirect POST requests to controller Post methods by default. Problem is, if I do so in the current state, HTTP POST requests will end up posting to `/api/Example/Get`.

I have looked into `MapGet` and `MapPost`, but the only implementations of these I can find short circuit the pipeline, handling and responding within the RequestDelegate passed. My controller methods are never reached this way.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

It would probably be worth adding, some controllers have extra GET and POST methods on them which are reached at `api/controller/action`, meaning I need to have a route to `{action}` specified somewhere. However doing so means that my default Get and Post methods are no longer accessible by just the controller name, hence adding `=Get` as a default action in MapRoute

Answer (score 3):

Of course every request will use the `Get` method because you told it to default it to:

```
routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action=Get}");
```

If you specify the literal segment (action token), i.e., `/api/example/get`, MVC sees that as the top-most level in the pecking order. That's why it always pick `Get` action inside your controller because you have specified the action token as well in the url.

**Don't do that with web api!**

Instead, web api uses `HttpVerb` to map the route. So you shouldn't specify the `HttpVerb` along with the Url. You supply the `HttpVerb`as the method type along with the request instead.

Think about api routes as identifying a resource / resource collection. It's different than how you think with MVC (RPC style).

Change to these and give it a try:

## Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

## Customer resource

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {   ...   }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {   ...   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `MapRoute` and just use default mvc routing? Get and Post methods should be accessible that way. Now regarding to other 
 extra GET and POST methods, there is an ordering logic on how the mvc picks which method first. Maybe you should update your post and post those extra methods too.